# OpenAPI : How to show response example of a nested array

Tags: openapi

Is there anyway to show an example response for a nested array. We want to make it exceedingly clear to the devs when this happens as there are a lot of these in our spec.

For example if in an array of people we needed an array of cities

```
          examples:
            Response:
              value:
                - Person:
                    Name: "Jim Beam"
                    Age: "41"
                    Address: "Clermont"
                    Address: "Chicago"
```